# Slightly blurry quality of html slides when enabling incremental: true in Quarto presentation

Tags: r, quarto, reveal.js

I noticed that when I set `incremental: true` in a Quarto revealjs presentation, I get slightly blurry slides after the first slide (check by switching back and forth between slide 1 and slide 2). Also the header moves very slightly up and down. This behavior cannot be seen when `incremental: false`.

Does anybody have an idea why this is? Example below.

````
---
title: "Test slide"
author: "John Doe"
format:
  revealjs:
    incremental: true
    theme: moon    
---

## Slide 1
- item a

## Slide 2
```{r, echo=F}
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) + geom_point()
p
```

## Slide 3
some additional text
````